# Unable to debug with IE11 in Visual Studio 2017 (error: there are no more files)

Tags: visual-studio, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2017, internet-explorer-11, visual-studio-debugging

I am using a Windows 10 64-bit laptop and when I try to debug any web project in Visual Studio 2017 (15.3.4) using IE11 as the browser, I get the error: "Unable to start program 'http://localhost/MyWebApp/'.  There are no more files".  The browser never even gets loaded, instead I get a popup with this error and nothing else.  This error doesn't make any sense or give a clue to what may be wrong.  Also, everything works fine with other browsers.

Please help.

[image]

Comment: Not really debug your app, just run it using "start without debugging", how about the result? If other browser has no this issue, please also think about your IE, for example, re-install/reset IE settings/clean cache or others. Or you could create a new simple web project, view the result.

Comment: Hi Jack, Thanks for your reply.  It happens with all web apps (new or existing) and I've tried cleaning the cache and resetting IE.  Also, I want to run with debug.  I will try re-installing IE, maybe that is the answer.

Comment: What about this issue now? Does it work well after you re-install the IE in your side?

Comment: Hi Jack,  I tried the reinstall but unfortunately it made no difference.  I still am unable to debug in IE11.

Comment: Could you share a screen shot about your project properties->Web? Do you really use the default IIS Express server? It seems that the URL was different from the default project URL like http://localhost:1333/xxx Do you set up the start item(like default.aspx) in your project? Do you debug or run a web app or a web site app? Do you have other IE Environment?

Comment: One suggestion is that please try to add the browser manually in your side: https://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/visual-studio-web-developer-express-starting-two-instances-of-internet-explorer-and-throwing-an-error

Comment: Hi Jack, Thanks for your suggestions.  I tried to manually add the browser so that it pointed to the 32-bit version.  I didn't get the error but the browser never loaded.  I am using IIS not IIS Express.  I have the Start Action set to Current Page.  I have tried with and without debugging.  With debugging it has the error, without it has no error but it never loads.

Comment: Like my previous reply, could you share a screen shot about the project properties->Web option? Please reset IE settings, and clean up the cache, view the result, just to make this issue clearly, could you run it in other browser like chrome or others?

Comment: I added the screenshot to the original post. This error happens on EVERY project, not just this one.  I have already tried clearing the cache and resetting IE parameters

Comment: Just to help you troubleshooting this issue, if you change the server from "Local IIS" to "IIS Express", and then debug it again, how about the result? At least, we could know that whether it is related to the browser or the project itself or the IIS configurations.

Comment: Just open your project in IIS, how about the result? If you copy your project to other Environment, how about the result? Actually it is hard for us to repro this issue with a sample, so I just provide some troubleshoot steps, if you get any latest information, please feel free to share it.

Comment: Hi Jack,  IIS Express has the same issue as IIS.  It works fine if you just go to it via IE without Visual Studio on the localhost or another server.  This seems to point to a problem with Visual Studio.

Comment: If so, I also agree with you, we would think about the VS IDE, if possible, please run your VS as the admin, and then reset VS settings: TOOLS->Import and Export Settings Wizard->Reset all settings->select “No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings”->Choose a Default Collection of settings. And then debug your app again or add a new default web project. Please set up the correct page as the start up page. If still no help, I suggest you re-install or repair your VS and update it to the latest version 15.3.5.

Comment: Hi Jack,  I am always running VS as admin and I have tried doing the VS settings reset.  I am on 15.0 because I had to downgrade because of a major bug in 15.3 where debugging typescript files doesn't work.  Before I downgraded, I did have this issue.  Hopefully VS 2017 15.4 comes out soon with this and the debugging typescript bug fixed.

Comment: Sorry for that we don't have the old version now, but it has the preview version 15.4, if possible, you could test it for the typescript debugging. In addition, I also suggest you repair your old VS version without updating to 15.3.5. View the result, if it was the setup issue, at least, we need to repair or re-install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps anyone.  It now works again since I upgraded to Visual Studio 2017 15.5.2

Comment: It's broken again in Visual Studio 2017 15.5.4

Answer (score 0):

Launch "Developer Command Prompt for VS2017" as Administrator.
From the command prompt run devenv.exe.

(Usually the path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe")

Works with Visual Studio 2017 15.9.20.